# how to implement copy and paste functionality in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, copy-paste

I am developing an app for iOS > 4.3.

I am looking for best practices regarding coping and pasting text between views or applications.

Comment: Do u want to move data between 2 or more views?? It'll b like copying and pasting i reckon...

Comment: Have you checked the Apple documentation? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `UIPasteboard`,

while setting:

```
   UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
   [pasteboard setString:yourtext];
```

while getting (if you have a label):

```
   UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
   pastelabel.text =  [pasteboard string];
```

and you can refer [Pasteboard Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbCopying.html) for more details.